# Concise pattern match on single case discriminated union in F#

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, discriminated-union

Say I have the following single case discriminated union:

```ml
type OrderId = OrderId of string
```

At some point I need the actual string. The way I've found for extracting it is:

```ml
let id = match orderId with OrderId x -> x
```

Is there a more concise way of doing this?

I understand that my use is a special case and the match makes sense in order to make sure you've covered the possibilities, just wondering if there's a way of doing something like:

```ml
let OrderId id = orderId
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You're almost there. Parentheses are required in order that the compiler interprets a let-bound as pattern matching:

```
let (OrderId id) = orderId
```

If `orderId` is a parameter of a function, you can also use pattern matching directly there:

```
let extractId (OrderId id) = id
```

Answer (score 19):

When you're using a discriminated union to hold a single value (which is a useful F# programming technique), then it might make sense to define it with a property for accessing the value:

```
type OrderId = 
  | OrderId of string 
  member x.Value = let (OrderId v) = x in v
```

The implementation of `Value` is using the pattern matching using `let` as posted by pad. Now, if you have a value `orderId` of type `OrderId`, you can just write:

```
let id = orderId.Value
```

However, the pattern matching using `(OrderId id)` is still quite useful, because property access will only work when the compiler already knows the type of `orderId` (so you would typically use pattern matching in function argument, but property access for other values).

Comment: Unfortunately, you lose type inference, requiring you often to specify the types, which can lead to more verbosity. I personally prefer a module method like `get` or `lift`, which won't have that problem and allows for piping, composition and a more dotless style in general (notwithstanding that this is a useful approach in many scenarios too)