# Is there a concise inline expression for unwrapping a single case discriminated union?

Tags: f#

I'm working through the basics of F# and am still at the point where I'm not sure what's possible or what's available.  I'm thinking there ought to be a better way to do this:

I'm looking at the common demonstration scenario of using this code for added type protection

```
type CustomerId = CustomerId of int
type OrderId = OrderId of int
```

At some point I have persistence code that needs to unwrap the integer:

```
dbcmd.Execute(CID = ???, OID = ???)
```

Option A: bulky but works

```
dbcmd.Execute(CID = match CustomerId with (CustomerId cid) -> cid, OID = match OrderId with (OrderId oid) -> oid)
```

Option B is derived from the answer in [Concise pattern match on single case discriminated union in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232187/concise-pattern-match-on-single-case-discriminated-union-in-f)

This requires 2 lines and if there are 4 or 5 things to unwrap I start to really dislike the 'distance' between the left and right side of the `let` statement -- I'm likely to eventually type something out of order

```
let (CustomerId cid, OrderId oid) = (CustomerId, OrderId)
dbcmd.Execute(CID = cid, OrderId = oid)
```

Option C: This is probably what I'll prefer if there's nothing better.  It is clear but consumes more vertical space than I would have hoped

```
let (CustomerId cid) = CustomerId
let (OrderId oid) = OrderId
dbcmd.Execute(CID = cid, OrderId = oid)
```

Option D: This is sort of what I'm hoping exists.  This doesn't actually work since this is the syntax for wrapping, not unwrapping, but you get the idea

```
dbcmd.Execute(CID = (CustomerId id), OID = (OrderId id))
```

Does concise syntax that resembles Option D exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually use one of these options, choosing between them pretty much intuitively. Mostly I prefer option 1, but it doesn't work if I need to make the constructor private.

### Option 1: specify patterns right in parameter declarations

You can do this, because function parameters don't have to be just plain identifiers, they can be patterns too.

```
let f (CustomerId cid) (OrderId oid) =
  let cmd = ...
  cmd.Execute( cid, oid )
```

### Option 2: create special accessor functions

```
type CustomerId = CustomerId of int
  with static member toInt (CustomerId id) = id

cmd.Execute( CustomerId.toInt cid, ... )
```

### Option 2b: same, but with instance member

```
type CustomerId = CustomerId of int 
  with member this.asInt = match this with (CustomerId id) -> id

cmd.Execute( cid.asInt, ... )
```

Comment: Option 1 is where I want to go, the problem is that the CustomerId/OrderId values were inside of a larger record rather than 'loose'.  However, I think that points at my true problem.  The cmd execution should be factored out into its own function that *does* take individual loose parameters -- let the calling function deal with organizing the parameters needing to be passed in.

Comment: You can nest patterns too.

Comment: Given `type Order = { Id : OrderId }`, you can easily deconstruct record and single case union in one go: `let f { Id = OrderId oid } = ...`

Answer (score 8):

You could also use a lambda without modifying or extending the type definition:

```
cid |> fun (CustomerId i) -> i
```